# ssh2_exec wget won't work

Tags: php, ssh

I want to download a file using ssh2_exec.
Things like xdotool work but wget/pkill don't.

Here's the code

```
function __construct($host, $user, $pw, $port) {
        $this->SSHC = ssh2_connect($host, 22);
        ssh2_auth_password($this->SSHC, $user, $pw);
}

function downloadFile() {
        ssh2_exec($this->SSHC, "wget http://path/to/file");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is still needed, but it would appear the issue is related somehow to the output from wget. If you run wget with the background option everything works fine:

`wget -b /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute paths to the programs (`/usr/bin/wget`). you can find the full paths by PUTTYing in and running:

```
which wget
```

Also take a look at the output from the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` streams in order to further debug your problems.

Comment: Thanks, absoulte doesn't work, but wget prints the error "Must be connected to a terminal", but I doesn't find anything on the internet

Comment: What command are you using in order to connect? If you dont have the -t parameter try adding it and see if that solves your problem.